# Word Add-in not creating buttons in the ribbon

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-2016

I'm working on an Office 2016 & Office 365 add-in using javascript and an XML manifest file. When I load the manifest in word online, everything works as expected. It creates a tab, and places buttons on that tab that call a function in the javascript file attached to the html file that is listed in the manifest file.

However, when I load this add-in into word 2016 (for windows desktop), it doesn't work. In fact, it opens a taskpane (on the side) instead of creating a new tab with buttons. Here is the document that lists the steps I followed to load the add-in into word for desktop ([Office Dev Center - Docs - Build Your First Word Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/word-add-ins), under the "Try this out in Word 2016 for Windows" section). See below for a snippet of my XML file.

I'm having the exact opposite problem of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876084/i-have-written-an-add-in-for-excel-2016-but-i-cannot-get-it-show-in-excel-online) question, and I've done exactly what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532706/how-to-create-new-tab-with-buttons-in-word-2016/36543898#36543898) question's response suggests, but it doesn't work.

XML (Modified from the original):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<OfficeApp
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
      xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
      xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

<Id>*-*-*-*-*</Id>

<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
<ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>

<DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso" />
<Description DefaultValue="Contoso"/>

<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://*" />

<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
  <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
  <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>

<Hosts>
  <Host Name="Document" />
</Hosts>
<DefaultSettings>
  <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://*" />
</DefaultSettings>

<Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <Hosts>
    <Host xsi:type="Document">
      <DesktopFormFactor>
        <GetStarted>
          <Title resid="contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>
          <Description resid="contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>
          <LearnMoreUrl resid="contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
        </GetStarted>
        <FunctionFile resid="contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
          <CustomTab id="contoso.Tab">
            <Group id="contoso.Events">
              <Label resid="contoso.EventsLabel" />
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
              </Icon>
              <Control xsi:type="Button" id="contoso.EventButton">
                <Label resid="contoso.EventButton.Label" />
                <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="contoso.EventButton.Label" />
                  <Description resid="contoso.EventButton.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                  <FunctionName>openEventWindow</FunctionName>
                </Action>
              </Control>
            </Group>
            <Label resid="contoso.Tab.Label" />
          </CustomTab>
        </ExtensionPoint>
      </DesktopFormFactor>
    </Host>
  </Hosts>

  <Resources>
    <bt:Images>
      <bt:Image id="contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://*" />
      <bt:Image id="contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://*" />
      <bt:Image id="contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://*" />
    </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
      <bt:Url id="contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://*" />
      <bt:Url id="contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://*" />
    </bt:Urls>

    <bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:String id="contoso.Tab.Label" DefaultValue="Contoso" />
      <bt:String id="contoso.EventButton.Label" DefaultValue="Add to Event" />
      <bt:String id="contoso.EventsLabel" DefaultValue="Events" />
      <bt:String id="contoso.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with Contoso!" />
    </bt:ShortStrings>

    <bt:LongStrings>
      <bt:String id="contoso.EventButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to browse the active events" />
      <bt:String id="contoso.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="The contoso Add In has loaded successfully!" />
    </bt:LongStrings>
  </Resources>
</VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

NOTE: This add-in works as I expect in Word 365, but not in Word 2016. Anyone have any ideas? Is there an option that I need to change in my install of Office 2016 maybe that is preventing them from loading right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-in commands (i.e., ribbon customization) was not available in Office 2016 RTM.  Instead, the functionality was added a few months later, and continues to be iterated and improved upon with each monthly build.

If you have Office 2016 RTM (e.g., if you purchased it as a disk / MSI install as a standalone version, rather than as part of an Office 365 subscription and the "evergreen" Office), you won't have Add-in commands enabled.

Just to check:  what version number do you see when you go to File --> Account?

[image]

Comment: My office version is 16.0.6741.2048. I have an Office 365 ProPlus subscription.

Comment: @RyanAndrews: Any success if you upgrade your Office installation?

Comment: @RyanAndrews: The documentation of the [Office Add-in Commands Samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples) states that the minimum required version is 16.0.6769.0000 or higher (16.0.6868.0000 is recommended).

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to install updates now. My work computer is still running windows 7. Not sure if that's an issue or not. When I try to tell office to install updates, it says "Updates are ready to be installed" but nothing happens. So i'm manually trying through windows update now

Comment: I've followed the steps here (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-the-First-Release-build-for-Office-365-for-business-customers-4dd8ba40-73c0-4468-b778-c7b744d03ead?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), but it didn't update my version of office.

Comment: Manually using the windows update tool (Checking for updates online) didn't update my version of Office 2016 either. I'm wondering if it's because this computer has windows 7...

Comment: I don't think it should have anything to do with Windows 7... But not sure what it might be.  Is there some setting in you Office365 account about whether you're on an immediate-release vs. deferred channel?... A separate non-office-js thread might get you better answers.

Comment: It says I'm on the deferred channel

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  If your office installation is part of an organizational account (Office 365 for Business), you probably won't have control of which channel you're on, though your account admin will.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt455210.aspx or https://www.msoutlook.info/question/office-update-channels.  Note that if you have your own Office 365 Home account (or if you sign up for an Office 365 developer account, free for first year and also free for MSDN subscribers -- http://dev.office.com/devprogram), you'll be able to get the latest updates.